# Apache Activiti Workflow Execution happens as a separate process or within the Activiti Process

Tags: activiti, azkaban

I have been investigating Azkaban and Apache Activiti for one of our Workflow Use Cases. What I understand is that each job within Azkaban runs as a separate process, is that the same with Activiti, or do Activiti Tasks run within the Activiti's main Process as separate threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activiti tasks run in the same process where the main Engine is running.

Depending on the presence or not of asynchronous activities in your flow, they will run in the same thread used when you invoke one of its APIs or by a pool of background threads.

That said, there is nothing that stops you from running specific steps of a workflow in a separate process (eg: a long running batch processing). This can be achieved in a number of ways, but the one I favor is to model tasks as "human tasks" and then use an external scheduler to pick those tasks using Activiti´s APIs (REST or Java) for actual execution. This approach is quite scalable and avoid some pitfalls related to transaction management that can arise if your tasks are too complex and/or take a long time do execute.

Answer (score 0):

In case Activiti engine is embedded within your application the tasks run in the thread which invoke the engine API (could be service task or user task). But what I understand from your question is perhaps you are interested in invoking the Activiti engine [remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323878/how-to-initiate-a-workflow-in-activiti-using-rest-api) using REST API in which case obviously the tasks run as different threads in container hosting Activiti engine.